# I got an error after installing a cordova push notification plugin

Tags: android, cordova, maven, push-notification

After Installing, **cordova push notification plugin**, am getting the following error when run the android application.

A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.

Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.

Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.jar

Required by:
         :android:unspecified

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

**BUILD FAILED**

Total time: 35.233 secs

**Error: Error code 1 for command: /Users/mac/Desktop/MyProject/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/mac/Desktop/MyProject/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true**

Comment: I'm having the same problem over here. Updating cordova android platform doesn't solve this problem.

Comment: In fact, my problem was related to the corporate proxy. Everything is working fine for me now.

Answer (score 0):

Updating phonegap should fix this, run this on the command line

```
npm i -g phonegap
phonegap platform android update
```